# compare string from file and get group by of results using shell/bash

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file like below :

```
h1 a 1
h2 a 1
h1 b 2
h2 b 2
h1 c 3
h2 c 3
h1 c1 3
h2 c1 3
h1 c2 3
h2 c2 3
```

I need output like :

```
2 a 1
2 b 2
6 c 3
```

I have tried with bash , somehow its not giving me the expected results.

```
cat sample.log | awk '{print $2 , $3}' | sort | uniq -c
2  
2 a 1
2 b 2
2 c 3
2 c1 3
2 c2 3
```

With below i am able to get the c* results, but a and b are missing .

```
 cat sample.log | awk '$2="c" {print $2 , $3}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -1
 6 c 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following.

```
awk '{sub(/[0-9]+/,"",$2);a[$2 OFS $3]++} END{for(i in a){print a[i],i}}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                       ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  sub(/[0-9]+/,"",$2)       ##Substitute digits from 2nd field with NULL.
  a[$2 OFS $3]++            ##Creating array with 2nd and 3rd field and increasing its occurence.
}
END{
  for(i in a){              ##Starting for loop here.
    print a[i],i            ##Printing array a element with index i and index i here.
  }
}
' Input_file                ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In case OP needs output in same sequence as Input_file then try following,

```
awk '
{
  sub(/[0-9]+/,"",$2)
}
!a[$2 OFS $3]++{
  count++
}
{
  b[count]=$2 OFS $3
  ++c[$2 OFS $3]
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print c[b[i]],b[i]
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use this `gnu-awk`:

```
awk '{ ch=substr($2, 1, 1); ++freq[ch OFS $3] } END { 
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"; for (i in freq) print freq[i], i }' file
```

```
2 a 1
2 b 2
6 c 3
```

Answer (score 1):

without `awk`

```
 $ sed -E 's/[^ ]+ (.).* /\1 /' file | sort | uniq -c

      2 a 1
      2 b 2
      6 c 3
```

Comment: Why 3 commands when it can be done with single awk? And you are an `awk` expert yourself :)